# There's any way to delete objects in VB6 without getting errors?

Tags: object, vb6

I need to simplify a program made in VB6, so I need to delete a lot of objects but don't want to delete one, run, get an error, fix it, run, get another error, a so on for every object.

I don't created the original program, so is very annoying try to think what someone else thought.
Plus, the code is not commented and is very dirty, the objects have the default names, like Label1, Timer12. WTF?
So I can't get a clue about what a timer does until I fully read the code.

Any idea?

Comment: By "Objects" do you mean controls? If you delete a control and something else references it, you'll get an error.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean; and yes that's the problem, I need to get all the references to that object to fix the program.

Comment: The easiest way to find all those references is to run the program after you've deleted the control surely? If you don't need all these controls for definite just delete them all in one fell swoop and then fix the 1000+ errors that occur.

Comment: In VB6 that's, as far I know, that's not posible because the compiler show the first error founded not all, and that's the problem. In VB.NET you get all the errors, in VB6 you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the original author didn't have much thought, true.  But then you're not giving it much thought either by thinking that the best approach will be to delete an object, run and see what happens, and then rinse and repeat until you have a fully working program.  Given your approach, by the time you've finished deleting all the objects - you won't have much left to run anyway!  (No data, *No Problem!*).

1. Look through the code in conjunction with running and debugging the application.  This will give you an idea of what it is trying to do (I am under the assumption there's not really much in the way of documentation for this project?)
2. Time to think of a new plan!  Sometimes re-writing from scratch is absolutely necessary rather than attempting to work with legacy code that is clearly hard to maintain and is far from optimum.  The downside is that this will take more time, on paper - but perhaps will save time in the long run.  This might be the time also to move away from VB6 and in to the .NET era.  Rewriting applications can let you do this too!
3. If a re-write is out of the question (such a shame), then you can't go through willy-nilly deleting objects!  The program *functions* with these objects.  So they've got to stay and you need to maintain it.
4. See (2).

Good luck, God speed.

**Or, given your comment**

*Rename* Label1 to something more appropriate.  Do a search replace *within that file* (Not the whole solution) to the new name, then correct any accidental errors and move on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the program have a lot, and when I say a lot I really mean a lot of controls, about 250, so imagine the logic behind all that. I try to do a new one in VB.NET but get exhausted just creating the GUI, to many controls with a lot of propertys to set. I think I'm going to make my own version of this program in NET, it seems to be the only solution tho this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the last option of Moo-Juice's answer, but slightly different: I would rename a control by adding an "x" to its name and run the project. 
If it runs, then remove the control, if it doesnt run, then rename the control back by removing the "x". 
This should not take more than 1 hour for about 250 controls

But first you might do something else: Instead of just deleting the unused controls, you might also want to look at the controls:

If there are so many controls then it might be possible to convert series of controls into a control array: This might clean up the code a lot as well, and give you a better overview of the remaining controls

When you cleaned up the controls have a look at their names, and rename them to something useful.

After that it is time to clean up the code in the same way.
You can [download MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/download.aspx) to help you with that.
It's a must for the lazy coder :)

Also place "Option Explicit" at the top of all code windows. This will make it easier for you to spot errors caused by not (properly) declared variables.
Do this after you have done **"Review Source Code" of MZ-Tools** though, as that might save you a lot of work :)